# Какие слова подходят под звуковую схему?

Tags: фонетика

Какие из этих слов (волки, чашки, верба, нитки, мешки, сетка) подходят под эту схему: 
первая буква - мягкий согласный, вторая буква - ударный гласный, третья - твердый согласный, четвертая - мягкий согласный, пятая - безударный гласный.

Comment: @Тамара007, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> первая буква - мягкий согласный

-- проходят дальше все слова.

> вторая буква - ударный гласный

-- отпали **мешкИ**.

> Третья - твердый согласный

-- прошли дальше все четыре оставшихся слова.

> Четвертая - мягкий согласный

-- отпали **вер[б]а** и **сет[к]а**.

> Пятая - безударный гласный.

-- условие выдержали и **чАшки**, и **нИтки**.

Comment: Спасибо большое! )